# How to get revit version of files upload in BIM360 translated before 2021

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to get revit versions for file upload in BIM360 which are translated before 2021.
We get revit version for files translated after 2021 using below link https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/:urn

Answer (score 2):

This was added only in November 2021 because there was no way to get that info. So if you have files translated before that, the Revit version will not be in the manifest.

Also see [blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/check-version-revit-file-hosted-cloud).